# NLTK Punkt Tokenizer: How to do Custom Sentence End Characters?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I tried using the solution provided here, which is a minimal example that works; with a few unicode characters instead.

[NLTK Sentence Tokenizer, custom sentence starters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746635/nltk-sentence-tokenizer-custom-sentence-starters)

**Example 1: Does not actually work**

This is provided in the StackOverflow question.

```py
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktLanguageVars

class BulletPointLangVars(PunktLanguageVars):
    sent_end_chars = ('.', '?', '!', '•')

tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(lang_vars = BulletPointLangVars())
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(u"• I am a sentence • I am another sentence")
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

The above at first glance looks like works, and provides the expected output on a first run. However, this fails if I remove the space preceding •, after some more debugging.

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected and actual output in your question?

Comment: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/2587; Looks solved. I guess I will copy-paste the answer eventually.